# HighCharts - what happens after the tooltip formatter function is run?

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

I have an issue with the tooltip not being rendered when in a certain state of my application. The application in context is quite complex and I cannot paste the whole file(s) here, so I want to try to debug myself, but I am quite stuck.

So I wonder, where can I follow the rendering of the returned format strings from the tooltip format function? (In the application state in question, I have made sure that the formatter function is run.)

I've tried following the execution flow in my browsers debug tools but got nowhere (unreadable files).

I have tried to debug in the browser, but highcharts.js is not readable in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can import `src` files to see unminified Highcharts files during debugging:

```
// Import Highcharts
import Highcharts from "highcharts/highcharts.src";
import exporting from "highcharts/modules/exporting.src";

exporting(Highcharts);
```

Or check the fragment you are interested in on GitHub: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/ec63b5ed6af61e6fda1d537632003782e00de028/ts/Core/Tooltip.ts#L248

**Docs:** https://code.highcharts.com/